# Cannot Access dict with duplicate values dynamically from Api - Python for Binance

Tags: python, api, dictionary, python-requests

I am attempting to format this Api
https://www.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allBookTickers

Here is an abbreviated version of the Api

> [{"symbol":"ETHBTC","bidPrice":"0.07200500","bidQty":"0.67800000","askPrice":"0.07203200","askQty":"7.19200000"},{"symbol":"LTCBTC","bidPrice":"0.01281100","bidQty":"10.90000000","askPrice":"0.01282500","askQty":"1.01000000"}]

Each dict is saved as an index in the list my issue is with the fact that each dict starts with 'symbol' rather then the name like 'ETHBTC'

I can call the index number but as their is hundreds of dicts in the api I need to find a method of being able to type in for instance 'ETHBTC' to call that dict?

This is what it would look like in an ideal world but I have no idea how to achieve this any help would be greatly appreciated?

```
> data = requests.get('https://www.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allBookTickers')
> data = data.json() 
> ltc = data['LTCBTC']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:-

```
import requests

#fetched data from url using requests
data = requests.get('https://www.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allBookTickers')

# creating json object from response
dataJson = data.json() 

# creating dictionary from json object using symbol value as key
dataDictionary = {d['symbol'] : d for d in dataJson}

# accessing dictionary object using symbol value
ltc = dataDictionary['LTCBTC']

print ltc

# now you can use ltc values by given keys as, and so on for other values
print ltc['askPrice']
```

In this code we created python dictionary from the response returned.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I was looking for very helpful!

Comment: Just attempting to understand this does "d for d in dataJson"

iterate over everything in datajson in order to find what you ask it to search for?

Thanks again

Comment: It's list comprehension for creating a dictionary in python. It will iterate every element of `dataJson` list, and create a dictionary by using `symbol` as key.